# Git/Gerrit push repo1 to repo2 with all branches

Tags: git

We have a project in Gerrit ( repo1 for example ) and we need to push the entire history and branches of repo1 to a new project repo2. Here are some of the steps performed so far

```
 git clone ssh://$USER\@$HOST:29418/repo1 
 for remote in `git branch -r | grep -v master`; do git branch --track $remote
 git remote remove origin
 git remote add origin ssh://${USER}\@${HOST}:29418/repo2
 and then ..
 cd /var/tmp/${project} && git push origin master && git push origin --all && git push       
 origin --tags
```

but it fails above asking me to pull the changes. Once I pull the changes, it errors out that I donot have any remote tacking setup. I am all confused now in this regard. How do i push a project with history and multiple branches to a new one. Any suggestions?

EDIT 1:

After trying the Rene's suggestion, i get this error :

```
failed to push some refs to 'ssh://$USER@$HOST:29418/repo2'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first merge the remote changes (e.g.,
hint: 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need 3 steps

```
git clone ssh://$USER\@$HOST:29418/repo1
```

Just add the `repo2` as another remote

```
git remote add repo2 ssh://${USER}\@${HOST}:29418/repo2
```

use a refspec and you don't need to create local branches

```
git push repo2 refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

**EDIT**

You can take a test-drive with my [GitDirStat](https://github.com/link-intersystems/GitDirStat) repository on github, e.g.

```
BASE_DIR=`pwd`
git clone https://github.com/link-intersystems/GitDirStat.git
git init --bare GitDirStat-repo2
cd GitDirStat
git remote add repo2 file://$BASE_DIR/GitDirStat-repo2
git push repo2 refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

> I am still getting this error:error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://$USER@$HOST:29418/repo2' hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do hint: not have locally.

The remote repository already contains branches that you want to push and git can not update them doing a fast-forward. So the branches you push are not in line with the remote branches.

You said that

> we need to push the entire history and branches of repo1 to a **new project repo2**

a new repo should be empty and thus you should not get this error.

If repo2 does **NOT** contain any important changes you can do a forced push. I would recommend to **make a backup clone first**.

You can do a forced push by either using `-f`

```
git push -f ...
```

or add the `+` to the [refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/zh/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)

```
+refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*
```

This forces a ref update and the commits that the refs pointed to before are lost.

Comment: So it does not matter if i keep the original remote repo. I just need to add the new one! Trying this out

Comment: @f-z-N You can push any ref to any repository that is configured. I updated my answer to give you a test-drive.

Comment: Thanks for the explanatio. It makes sense.. I am still getting this error:

Comment: Thanks for the explanatio. It makes sense.. I am still getting this error:error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://$USER@$HOST:29418/repo2'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first merge the remote changes (e.g.,
hint: 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: @f-z-N I thought repo2 is empty, because you said it is a new repo or does it already contain other work?

Comment: I created a repo but checked the option to have an initial commit. Guess that is creating this issue. I have now created a bare repo and trying again.

Comment: @f-z-N If you create a repo with an initial commit you will have at least one master branch and if you try to push the other repo git will correctly reject it by default. If it is just an initial commit you can do a forced push (if you have the permission in gerrit)